# json string manipulation for use with d3.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

So I have one of two questions. How can I either manipulate a JSON string data structure in javascript so that from

```
[  
   {  
      "Name":"A170",
      "Values":{  
         "Level 1":1,
         "Level 2":22,
         "Level 3":22,
         "Level 4":1
      }
   },
   {  
      "Name":"A220",
      "Values":{  
         "Level 1":2,
         "Level 2":1,
         "Level 3":1,
         "Level 4":1
      }
   }
]
```

I get this structure instead?

```
[  
   {  
      "Name":"A170",
      "Level 1":1,
      "Level 2":22,
      "Level 3":22,
      "Level 4":1
   },
   {  
      "Name":"A220",
      "Level 1":2,
      "Level 2":1,
      "Level 3":1,
      "Level 4":1
   }
]
```

Or my alternate question would be how to modify the d3 grouped data chart code to make it work with the first data structure. Here's what I have so far that works fine with the second (desired) data structure: http://jsbin.com/tutigaxevo/edit?js,output All help is appreciated. I am not much of a JS guy.

Comment: do you really have the data in string format or is it an object/array?

Comment: I believe it's an object array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manipulating a JSON string data structure can be done this way.

```js
var myJson = [  
   {  
      "Name":"A170",
      "Values":{  
         "Level 1":1,
         "Level 2":22,
         "Level 3":22,
         "Level 4":1
      }
   },
   {  
      "Name":"A220",
      "Values":{  
         "Level 1":2,
         "Level 2":1,
         "Level 3":1,
         "Level 4":1
      }
   }
];

myJson = myJson.map(function(value) {
var tempObj = value;
  Object.keys(value).forEach(function(key){
      if (typeof value[key] === 'object') {
        Object.keys(value[key]).forEach(function(val) {
          tempObj[val] = value[key][val];
        });
        delete tempObj[key];
      }
  })
return tempObj;
});

console.log(myJson);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me in JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/hopotovuhi/edit?js,console

Comment: It is working fine. I've just checked. check the img screenshot https://s3.postimg.org/mk5zbyaxf/js_BIn.png

Comment: so what is the [object Object] representing? and yes, you are right. Its working fine. Thank you for that.

Comment: It is the type of the value beside it. The way, values get printed in console differs from navigator to navigator